# Change parent of div when screen size is reduced

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm trying to change the parent div a child is attached to when the screen size is reduced.
Here is my code:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="menu">Menu 1</div>
<div id="testing">Testing 1</div>
<div id="boxed">
    <div id="box-01" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-02" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-03" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-04" class="boxes">
        <div id="menu-right">Menu 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-05" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-06" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-07" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box-08" class="boxes"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#menu {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#menu-right {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
}

#testing {
    font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.boxes {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}

#boxed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    top: 64px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9998;
}
```

I've also got a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/20/

So 'menu-right' is currently the child of 'box-04', when box 4 is in the top right corner, but when the screen size is reduced the menu also drops down. I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to change which parent the child is attached to when the screen size is reduced, so when box 4 drops down it will be attached to box 3 and so on. So the menu always stays attached to the top right hand box.
Or maybe there is an easier way to achieve this, can't seem to figure it out.
Hopefully that makes sense, I'm still a beginner.
​

Comment: why dont you set width and height in % in place of px

Comment: @vinique because I want the menu to move across by 100px (width of the red box) every time the window size is reduced to knock the red boxes down a line, i.e. always staying inline with the red box that is furthest to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the width of **#boxed** on resize, calculate how many **.boxes** fit in a row (#boxed width / .boxes width) and attach **#menu-right** to that box.

Use for instance:

```
.resize()
```

[resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
appendTo()
```

[appendTo()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo)